# Хороший и краткий учебник по компьютерным сетям

Tags: сеть, книги

Доброго времени суток.

Прошу совета по кратким пособиям по компьютерным сетям. Я - программист, но вот с пониманием работы сетей и протоколов у меня плоховато. Хочу подтянуться.

Не нужны учебники на 1к листов, я хочу почитать связный материал и быстро узнать что такое DHCP, DNS, WINS, Шлюзы, DNS-суффиксы и так далее. Я конечно мог бы просто пройтись по википедии и почитать определения, но это было бы не совсем связно, я хочу узнать что происходит от момента втыкания патчкорда в сетевую карту и до момента доступа к интернету, что ОС делает сама, а что иногда приходится делать в ручную. Если таковые встречали - посоветуйте пожалуйста.

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Вас  интересует программный аспект?
То есть протоколы модели OSI и как с ними работать.

Или как обжимать кабели, настраивать маршрутизаторы, прокладывать сети?

Answer (score 3):

Э. Таненбаум "Компьютерные сети"

Answer (score 2):

Самая короткая из знакомых мне полезных - Й.Снейдер "Эффективное программирование TCP/IP" - примерно 300 страниц.
А вообще, очень хорошо разжеванный материал - Д. Камер "Сети TCP/IP" - тут уже страниц 800, но кто мешает выбрать отдельно интересующие главы, в частности в начале книги очень хорошо и доступно описан механизм работы сетей с нуля, этих глав Вам на первое время будет достаточно.